# in_app_purchase ,I get two prices but cannot distinguish whether the user is eligible to use the discount or not

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

When a subscription has a discounted price, I get two prices but cannot distinguish whether the user is eligible to use the discount or not .

I added an offer to a subscription
[image: I added an offer to a subscription]

When I use the `queryProductDetails` method to get List based on its product id, the length of the list obtained is 2, which are the preferential price and the normal price, but I don’t know which one should be displayed to the user. There is no list in ProductDetails Describing whether the user is eligible to use the discount, the actual payment may be different from the displayed price. I want to show the user the actual price he paid. What should I do?

```dart
    Set<String> kIds = <String>{productId!};
    final ProductDetailsResponse response =
        await _iap.queryProductDetails(kIds);
    if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
      if (response.error != null) _handleError(response.error!);
    }
    List<ProductDetails> products = response.productDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
List<ProductDetails> products =
            await IAPUtil.showSaleProducts(modeEntity.productId);
        if (products.isNotEmpty) {
          vipModeList[i].priceUnit = products.first.currencySymbol;

          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            if (products.first is GooglePlayProductDetails) {
              ProductDetailsWrapper skuDetails =
                  (products.first as GooglePlayProductDetails).productDetails;
              print('优惠长度:${skuDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails?.length}');
              vipModeList[i].vipPrice = '${products.first.rawPrice}';
              if (skuDetails.subscriptionOfferDetails?.length == 1) {
                vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '';
              } else {
                vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '${products.last.rawPrice}';
              }
            }
            // vipModeList[i].vipPrice = '${products.first.rawPrice}';
            // vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '';
            // if (products.length > 1) {
            //   vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '${products.last.rawPrice}';
            // }
          } else {
            if (products.first is AppStoreProductDetails) {
              SKProductWrapper skProduct =
                  (products.first as AppStoreProductDetails).skProduct;
              vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '';
              vipModeList[i].vipPrice = '${products.first.rawPrice}';
              if (skProduct.introductoryPrice != null) {
                vipModeList[i].oldPrice = '${products.first.rawPrice}';
                vipModeList[i].vipPrice = skProduct.introductoryPrice!.price;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I processed the product data I got this way, but not sure if it's the best way